# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql

Últimamente ha sucedido que una base de datos en MySQL ha estado fallando. El error que sale es este:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

He buscado soluciones en otros sitios y todas hablan de cómo solucionar el problema puntual pero ninguna explica el origen del error y por qué a veces sale de forma que pareciera ser aleatoria.

Así que mi pregunta es:

**¿Qué significa este error?** y **¿Qué significa que sólo salga a veces?**

Sé que con reiniciar MySQL se soluciona pero no quiero estar haciendo eso por siempre.

Información que puede servir de algo:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- MySQL 5.5.46
- Estoy usando Prestashop

Espacio en disco:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        30G  4.5G   24G  16% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  340K  100M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Número máximo de conexiones

```
$ mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;
...
max_connections     151
```

Y como podrán ver, los usuarios activos no superan los 20 al mismo tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quien arroja ese error? que sistema operativo usas? has visto los logs de Mysql?

Comment: Está asociado a una consulta en particular o sale cuando intentas abrir la conexión?

Comment: @ArieCwHat agregué la información que tengo. No he visto los logs.

Comment: @amenadiel no tengo idea, es una base de datos en producción y sale quizá cuando un cliente intenta hacer algo, pero no siempre.

Comment: Vas a tener que aislar el problema. A lo mejor hay alguna query que no pasa por el proceso de abrir conexión

Comment: Revisa tu archivo `/etc/my.cnf` , mira a ver si en él hay un valor parecido a  `socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` el error parece indicar que MySQL busca un socket de conexión en una carpeta y no lo encuentra, dicho archivo suele estar en `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` y no en `/var/run/mysqld/`. En todo caso, en tu archivo de configuración la ruta del socket debe ser correcta, ese es el origen del error. De hecho, es extraño que la carpeta se llame, en tu caso, `mysqld`

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo la ruta correcta y el archivo existe

Comment: Usas algún framework? Tienes como hacer un log de consultas a la base de datos? Cuantos usuarios se conectan simultáneamente? Tu Programa Cierra las conexiones o utiliza una sola? Cuantas conexiones simultaneas permite tu base de datos? Cuales son los permisos de tu socket virtual? Tienes muy poca información como para darte una respuesta :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat wow, gracias. Son demasiadas cosas que no sé pero pensando en esas preguntas me da una idea de lo que tengo que investigar. Voy a buscar la información y actualizar la pregunta luego.

Comment: En realidad el archivo socket es un pseudo-archivo creado por el mismo MySQL, éste es creado cuando conectas a tu BD y cuando cierras la conexión es destruido. Me extraña que tu carpeta se llame `mysqld`, para probar, cambia la línea de socket en tu `my.cnf` por `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, cierra y abre MySQL y creo que funcionará.

Comment: "¿El WampServer o lo que sea que uses, está activo? - Ruben"